# Why does this Sidekiq readme say I need to create a secure session cookie?

Tags: oauth, sinatra, sidekiq

So I want to do standalone github oauth to allow github team and/or specific repo users access to the Sidekiq web dashboard.  In looking at the [readme](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring) section titled "Standalone with GitHub OAuth" it says to "create a secure session cookie" and then it shows:

```
openssl rand -base64 48
```

Why does a user need to go to the command line and generate what appears to be a base 64 hash string?  What does the author mean? Doesn't it make more sense to send a user to a web page where they confirm their github credentials so they can view the sidekiq web dashboard?  [In this example](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra-auth-github-test/blob/master/config.ru), you can see the user has a web page to confirm their github credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The session cookie is for CSRF protection and has nothing to do with GitHub OAuth.  It requires a secret, which is what is being generated by that openssl command.